# Pass variable from bash script to HTML

Tags: html, bash

I have a bash script that contains a variable. In the same script, I have an HTML section that, for now, outputs "Hello".

I'd like the HTML section of the bash script to retrieve a variable, and display that in the same heading as the "Hello" section. Essentially, the output on the HTML page should be something like this "Hello Adam".

For now, as simple as it gets, my bash script code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

firstname="Adam"

echo $firstname

cat << _EOF_
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>

</body>
</html>

_EOF_
```

How do I get the variable in the HTML section so that it can display the $firstname variable?

For reference, I currently run the script using `git-bash` by executing `sh {name-of-script} > test.html`

Comment: You write `$firstname` in the here doc...

Comment: @thatotherguy sorry what do you mean?

Comment: `<h1>Hello $firstname</h1>`

Comment: I feel very stupid! That works. If you want to put your answer as an answer to the question rather than a comment, I'll accept it :) Thanks!

Comment: Side note: if you use `sh myscript`, you'll run into problems when using Bash specific features such as arrays. You might not even actually run Bash (on Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is Dash). To avoid that and let the script use the interpreter specified in the shebang line, make it executable and run it with `./myscript` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular variable expansion in unquoted here documents:

```
# Hello Adam
firstname="Adam"
cat << EOF
Hello $firstname
EOF
```

If you want certain values to not be expanded, escape them:

```
# $firstname is Adam
cat << EOF
\$firstname is $firstname
EOF
```

If you don't want any values to be expanded, quote the delimiter:

```
# $firstname is not expanded in quoted heredocs
cat << "EOF"
$firstname is not expanded in quoted heredocs
EOF
```